# Type Script BeforeUnloadEvent not firing

Tags: javascript, typescript, onbeforeunload

In my application I have an comment box where I would like to display a message that it was not saved. In the function warnOpenEditor I have added window.onbeforeunload event but it will not fire. Attached TS and html file.

> Is there anything else I need to do for this event to fire?
>     TS file

```
import 
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
        beforeUnloadHander(event) {
        if (this.IsTouched = true) {
           event.returnValue = 'You have unfinished changes!';
        }
    }
    private cancel() {
    this.IsTouched = false;
    if (this.comments.length === 0) {
        this.hideComments();
    } else {this.hideEditor();}
    this.commentText = "";}
    private warnOpenEditor() {
        this.IsTouched = true;
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            this.$commentForm.fadeTo(100, 0.3).fadeTo(100, 1.0);}
    }
}
```

SideCommentsComponet.html

```
                <p class="comment" [innerHTML]="comment.Content | newline">
```

Comment: due to your recent edit your code and your question do not match. For example: you mention adding `window.onbeforeunload` in the `warnOpenEditor` function but your code does not reflect this. As a result your question will be harder to answer for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to move unload event out of method?

You should use this code

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    //check your comment box value to show message
}
```

Comment: No sure what you mean should it be window.onbefore?

Comment: private warnOpenEditor() {
   
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        this.$commentForm.fadeTo(100, 0.3).fadeTo(100, 1.0);
    }
}window.onbeforeunload = (event)=> {
        console.log("Changes you made may not be saved.");
    }

Comment: In the TS file?

Comment: You should change way implement for beforeunload event

Comment: I updated the post is that correct I am still not getting the message?

Comment: @HienNguyen `@HostListener` is an Angular decorator, right? OP did not mention he uses Angular so not sure how helpful this is.

Comment: Can you post full type script source file here?

Comment: Can you add SideCommentsComponent.html file?

Comment: @HienNguyen why will the  cancel() function not reset the isTouch Flag ? If the user cancels the comment I dont want the message to be displayed,

Comment: Yes I am getting the message now, just all the time when the page loads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188484/discussion-between-jefferson-and-hien-nguyen).